# pigpio wave_add_serial unreadable

Tags: raspbian, serial, uart, pigpio

I got some trouble with my sample code while trying to use pigpio as software UART implement.
I can read from RX pin but write to TX pin became unreadable
Those are my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pigpio
import time
import sys

TXPin=24
RXPin=18
serialpi = pigpio.pi()
serialpi.set_mode(18, pigpio.INPUT)
serialpi.set_mode(TXPin, pigpio.OUTPUT)

TEXT = 'ATH\n' 
msg = bytearray()
msg.extend(TEXT)
baudrate = int(sys.argv[1])

serialpi.wave_add_new()
serialpi.wave_add_serial(TXPin, baudrate, msg, 8, 8)
wid = serialpi.wave_create()
serialpi.wave_send_once(wid)
serialpi.wave_delete(wid)
serialpi.stop()
```

And this is the output when I try execute it:

```
�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������80�80�00�80�80�80�80�80�80�00�80�00�00�80�00�80�80�80�80�00�80�80�80�80�00�00�80�80�80�80������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

RING

NO CARRIER
```

Appreciate your help and time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.

ATH\n is written to GPIO24.

You can use [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) to check the transmission.

Alternatively use the following pigs commands (change 9600 to the baud rate you are using).

pigs slro 24 9600 8 # bit bang read serial data from GPIO24

Call your script several times and then

pigs -a slr 24 1000 # read up to 1000 characters of bit bang data

```
$ pigs slro 24 9600 8
$ pigs slr 24 1000
0
$ ./q.py  9600
$ ./q.py  9600
$ ./q.py  9600
$ ./q.py  9600
$ ./q.py  9600
$ pigs -a slr 24 1000
20 ATH
ATH
ATH
ATH
ATH
```

I did modify your script slightly to make sure the wave is transmitted before the program is exited.

```py
serialpi.wave_send_once(wid)

while serialpi.wave_tx_busy():
   time.sleep(0.01)

serialpi.wave_delete(wid)
```

Comment: Thank you joan, I can also can read from pin 24 but mine cannot display as string like yours:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pigs -a slr 24 1024
25 \x81\xa1\x0d\x9a\xc1\x81\xa1\x0d\x9a\xc1\x81\xa1\x0d\x9a\xc1\x81\xa1\x0d\x9a\xc1\x81\xa1\x0d\x9a\xc1

Comment: Im using a SIM900A gsm module with tx connect to rpi2 pin 18, rx connect to pin 24. I tried screen /dev/ttyAMA0 9600 with default rpi2 rx tx pins, everything work fine and clear , do I have to do some more convert before pass TEXT into serial?

Comment: Your string doesn't look like ASCII text.  Make sure your GSM module uses 3V3 levels.  Have you also connected the grounds?